# How to find three probabilities with two different values or ratings?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, causality, inference

I would like to know how to find three probabilities of two values....

Specifically...I want to know the three soccer venues (HOME DRAW AWAY) proabilities with two ratings...

Example: I have two values for two teams...

HOME: 575 points
AWAY: 325 points

Possible match prediction..
HOME - 47%
DRAW - 21%
AWAY - 32%

Is there a way to calculate these possible outcomes?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the probabilities it is :

Team 1

p(HOME) = number of points scored HOME/ total points (HOME + DRAW + AWAY)

p(DRAW) = number of points scored DRAW/ total points (HOME + DRAW + AWAY)

p(AWAY) = number of points scored AWAY/ total points (HOME + DRAW + AWAY)

Comment: Why should ratios of *points* have anything to do with *probabilities* of particular outcomes?  Maybe there is a model that suggests this, but at least you should be explicit about what assumptions you have made that would justify these formulas. You also seem--very confusingly--to be using "HOME", "DRAW", and "AWAY" simultaneously to refer to outcomes and to points. The OP has only two point values: the total points scored when away and the total points scored when at home. "DRAW" is meaningless in that sense.

Comment: @whuber You do not seem to be clear on what you want. These are the prior probabilities

Comment: Umm.. I don't want anything: I did not ask this question.  I have weighed in as a moderator because your answer not only is unclear, it seems to make no sense.  I would like to encourage you to clarify what you are saying and provide some justification for it.

Comment: I want to predict the outcome of a soccer game..I have two ratings and I would like to know if it is possible to get the percentages of a win, draw or lose...or team 1 wins, draw or team 2 wins.. @ccsv

Comment: @user44049 What are the 2 scores? Just the current points? If so you cannot because you have insufficient data.

Comment: Are ratings....ELO ratings!